# Delete links between turtles with different breeds

Tags: netlogo

I would like to drop links between one turtle and another one with different breed if a condition is satisfied. 
I am using the following code to do this:

```
ask one-of turtle1 [
if any? my-out-links with [breed = turtle2]
 [ask one-of out-link-neighbors with [breed = turtle2 and value < 0.7]  ;; value should refer to a neighbour's characteristics and it represents my condition
  [die]  
   ]
]
```

But the links seems to be kept. No link has been deleted.

Could you please tell me what it is wrong in my code and how to fix it accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `turtle1` and `turtle2` are two breeds of turtles. If so,

```
if any? my-out-links with [breed = turtle2]
```

will never find any such out-links as you are checking to see if any of `my-out-links` are of breed `turtle2`, and of course no *links* are of that breed. What you want is to know if the turtle at the other end of the link is of breed `turtle2`. Since these are directed links, the turtle you want to check is at `end2`.

```
if any? my-out-links with [[breed] of end2 = turtle2]
```

will let you know if the any of the turtles at the other end of `my-out-links` are of breed `turtle2`.

The line

```
ask one-of out-link-neighbors with [breed = turtle2 and value < 0.7] [die]
```

may do more than you intend. It asks a link-neighbor *turtle* of breed `turtle2` and with `value < 0.7` to die.  That will indeed kill the link as well (since it has lost its `end2`), but if you want to kill the link and not the turtle at the other end you could do all this in a single line

```
ask one-of turtle1 [
ask one-of my-out-links with [[breed = turtle2 and value < 0.7] of end2] [die]
]
```

If there are no such out-links, then you will be asking `nobody` and the ask will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you Charles. Value is turtles-own and not link's: could your suggestions be applied as well?

Comment: I've assumed that `value` is `turtles-own` in the code above. In the last code snip, `end2` is the turtle at the far end of the link.  Thus `breed` and `value` of `end2` refer to the `breed` and `value` of that turtle.

Comment: Thank you, Charles